# Как бороться с одинаковым кодом?

Tags: c#, рефакторинг

Есть проект, в котором около 30 .cs файлов, в каждом из которых есть одинаковый код, будь то инициализация шрифта, функция копирования и т.д. Как это можно вынести в одно место и вызывать одной строкой? Чтобы не создавать .dllек

Comment: А что мешает выделить одинаковый код в отдельный класс/метод?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский в некоторых формах есть richtextbox, а в классе он его не видит

Comment: Общение с richtextbox оставляете в форме, общий код - выносите в классы и их методы. Методы уже вызываете в формах, таким образом снижая дублирование.

Comment: Создайте класс, в котором реализуйте общий код (для того же RichTextBox), а от него наследуйте те, в которых этот код нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать преобразовывать данные в "универсальный вид", который далее легко накладывается на вызовы API.
Например, копирование в буфер может быть реализовано как:

```
public static void CopyToClipboard(ClipboardObject copiedText)
{
    var type = copiedText.ObjectType; //в буфер обмена можно помещать как форматируемый, так и не форматируемый текст, у них будут разные типы
    var data = copiedText.Data;

    /*Win API calls, etc.*/
}

public static ClipboardObject ExtractText(TextBox textBox)
{
    return new ClipboardObject(textBox.Text, ClipboardObjectType.Simple); // ClipboardObjectType - это отдельный наш enum.
}

public static ClipboardObject ExtractText(RichTextBox textBox)
{
    return new ClipboardObject(???, ClipboardObjectType.Html); // ClipboardObjectType - это отдельный наш enum.
}
```

Далее в event'е кнопки будет что-то вроде:

```
public void OnCopyButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
    var obj = ClipboardManager.ExtractText(this.textArea);

    ClipboardManager.CopyToClipboard(obj);
}
```

Код я сильно подсократил, чтобы оставить идею.